How can I combine p-values estimated for individual variables within a single dataset using different statistical methods?
I'm analyzing a multivariate dataset with two classes (case/control). I've calculated p-values for each variable to test their discrimination perfomance using two different methods: 1) univariate t-tests, followed by multiple testing correction, and 2) PLS regression and permutation testing to establish a null distribution H0. The H0 is used to estimate p-values for the PLS regression coefficients.
So, I have two p-values for each variable, obtained from fundamentally different methods. Can the pairs of two p-values obtained for each feature be combined using the Fisher's method? Are these values independent?

As a general proposition, you should expect that all p-values computed from a single dataset are not independent.  That's especially so when two p-values are testing the same or similar hypotheses.

On a similar note: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605859/what-can-i-do-if-i-want-to-apply-fishers-method-or-some-other-method-of-combin/605878#605878

There is some missing information here that would help answer this question. First, it's not clear how many variables you have here. If you are testing several different pairs via t-tests, then I think there can be problems with that, particularly if you are adding PWCs into the mix. What is the overall objective? I'm not sure what you are trying to discriminate here, but I'm guessing other methods would be more suitable. It would also help to know what type of variables these are. For example, advice may change based off subjective vs objective measures used here.

thank you very much for your replies. I'm trying to identify discriminant variables in a two-class multivariate data set (50 samples x 200 variables). The most simple way is to use t-tests followed by FDR. However I typically also use other multivariate models that combined with permutation testing, let me estimate a p-value for each variable. For example, using PLS I can use the null distribution of regression vectors from a permutation test to estimate a p-value for the value in the original regression vector.
